# Crash on one specific Unity scene in iOS build - TexturesMetal::AddCreatedTexture

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I am having a crash only on one specific scene in my AR Foundation Unity build with the following error.

---

### Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
VM Region Info: 0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4362387424
REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
UNUSED SPACE AT START

```
  __TEXT                   10404c000-104050000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...lycoroTestApp
```

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [5380]
Triggered by Thread:  28

Thread 28 name:
Thread 28 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib               0x0000000195ac5ac0 objc_retain + 16 (objc-object.h:636)
1   UnityFramework                 0x00000001066d5320 TexturesMetal::AddCreatedTexture(TextureID, id, bool) + 32 (TexturesMetal.mm:481)
2   UnityFramework                 0x0000000106634828 GfxDeviceWorker::RunCommand(ThreadedStreamBuffer&) + 21972 (GfxDeviceWorker.cpp:0)
3   UnityFramework                 0x00000001066aa2ec GfxDeviceWorkerAutoreleasePoolProxy + 68 (GfxDeviceMetal.mm:5242)
4   UnityFramework                 0x0000000106636bd0 GfxDeviceWorker::RunExt(ThreadedStreamBuffer&) + 92 (GfxDeviceWorker.cpp:389)
5   UnityFramework                 0x0000000106636b68 GfxDeviceWorker::Run() + 156 (GfxDeviceWorker.cpp:373)
6   UnityFramework                 0x000000010662ef70 GfxDeviceWorker::RunGfxDeviceWorker(void*) + 12 (GfxDeviceWorker.cpp:352)
7   UnityFramework                 0x00000001062289f8 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 496 (Thread.cpp:81)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001c9777c74 _pthread_start + 288 (pthread.c:887)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001c977c878 thread_start + 8

---

At first I thought it was because I was missing the Environmental Probe manager in that scene (no). Then I thought perhaps it was because I was using a specific shader that didn't use a _MainTex. But I use that shader no problem in other working scenes.

And then I built the scene with only a simple primitive and my UI and still received this error. After that crash the scene did open successfully, but obviously the problem is still there. The UI is the exact same as the other working scenes.

I can't find out much about this specific error: TexturesMetal::AddCreatedTexture - only that there may be this bug with GLES3 and PVRTC textures - but they aren't present in the most recent build.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-crash-in-uploadtexture-at-texturesmeta-dot-mm-or-drawbufferranges-at-gfxdevicegles-dot-cpp-using-atlas-with-pvrtc-compress

The scene works perfectly in Android - it only crashes in iOS.

Any ideas? Full report below.

---

I ran a Product>Analysis in Xcode and it gave me this warning:

---

/Users/xcodeclub/Downloads/Eliot Silver/Classes/UI/UnityView.mm:200:5: nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value

---

For this bit of Code in UnityView.mm:

---

static Class UnityRenderingView_LayerClassMTL(id self_, SEL _cmd)

{

return NSClassFromString(@"CAMetalLayer");

}

static Class UnityRenderingView_LayerClassNULL(id self_, SEL _cmd)

{

return NSClassFromString(@"CALayer");

}

@implementation UnityRenderingView

- (Class)layerClass

{

return nil;

}

- (void)InitializeForAPI:(UnityRenderingAPI)api

{

IMP layerClassImpl = api == apiMetal ? (IMP)UnityRenderingView_LayerClassMTL : (IMP)UnityRenderingView_LayerClassNULL;

class_replaceMethod(object_getClass([UnityRenderingView class]), @Selector(layerClass), layerClassImpl, UIView_LayerClass_Enc);

}

@End

Comment: Turns out this error wasn't the cause of the crash. It was audio related. It still crashes on first open of the scene though, which is annoying.